# Different Number of Products per row in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a unusual Magento request from a client that I cant seem to figure out.

We need to be able to display a different number of products per row in each row.

For example in row one we need to display 3 products and in the second row 4 products.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This one requires a bit of programming.

I've solved this by adding a custom attribute to categories that I call "number of products across". I can set it to any number, and this number is used when looping through the products in the template (app/design/frontend/base/{{theme_name}}/catalog/product/list.phtml)

Each product wrapper div is assigned a class along the lines of product_{{num}}_across, and the css for that class will determine the layout.